# transform hashtable to object with recursion

Tags: powershell

I've got a function that returns a hashtable and i need to transform the keys into nested objects, but i am losing my mind.

here is a hardcoded example of the hashtable I'm dealing with

```
# $hash = SomeFunctionThatReturnsAhashTable

$hash = @{
    'root.Blubb' = @(5)
    'root.controller.haha' = 'hoho', 'hoho'
    'root.controller.hugo' = @(12)
    'root.controller.name' = '10.3.3.171', '10.3.3.172'
    'root.controller.renate' = @(123)
    'root.controller.test' = 2, 2
    'root.controller.upsala' = @('handy')
    'root.t.t1.wert' = @(1)
    'root.t.t2.wert' = @(2)
    'root.test' = 1, 2
}
```

the following is the idea of what i want the hashtable to be transformed into

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{
    root = [pscustomobject]@{
        Blubb = @(5)
        controller = [pscustomobject]@{
            haha = 'hoho', 'hoho'
            hugo = @(12)
            name = '10.3.3.171', '10.3.3.172'
            renate = @(123)
            test = 2, 2
            upsala = @('handy')
        }
        t = [pscustomobject]@{
            t1 = [pscustomobject]@{
                wert = @(1)
            }
            t2 = [pscustomobject]@{
                wert = @(2)
            }
        }
        test = 1, 2
    }
}
```

I'm trying to split on the '.' and return sub-objects, but i don't know how to get it done. If there's a better way to go about this, please let me know. this is what i have so far.

```
function keytoobject ($key, $value) {
    if ($key.contains('.')) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            ($key.substring($key.indexof('.')+1)) = (keytoobject $key.substring($key.indexof('.')+1) $value)
        }
    } else {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            $key = $value
        }
    }
}

$hash.Keys | % {
    keytoobject $_ ($hash[$_])
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this scenario would `root.controller` have a value? I ask because it could be a complication that should be addressed how to handle it

Comment: the desired result is that the value of root.controller would be a single object with 6 properties as shown in the second section of provided code.

Comment: I mean this in the nicest way possible: "Why do you have data formed like this"?

Comment: Are you sure that's what the hash table looks like to start with? It is very weird to name the values as if they where properties of an object...

Comment: Yes. I was trying to help someone on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/49ygde/shove_structured_data_into_psobject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh my gosh! I have been working on this for a few hours now but I think I have something that is working. I had to use `Add-Member` more than I would have liked but it was the way I got to create empty objects so they would not be equal to `$null`. That was important because that test determined with new nested object need be created.

```
function Add-NestedObject($sourceObject, $path, $objectData){
    # This function will add the object $objectToNest into $sourceObject into the location named by $parentPath
    $currentPath,$remainingPath = $path.Split(".",2)

    # Check to see if the object contains the following subproperty.
    if($sourceObject.$currentPath -eq $null){
        # This property does not exist and needs to be created. Use an empty object
        Add-Member -Name $currentPath -TypeName PSObject -InputObject $sourceObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Value (New-Object -TypeName PSObject)
    }

    # Are there more elements to this path?
    if($remainingPath){
        # There are more nested objects. Keep passing data until we get to the point where we can populate it.  
        Add-NestedObject ($sourceObject.$currentPath) $remainingPath $objectData
    } else {
        # Now we can use the data and populate this object.
        $props = @{} 
        $objectData | ForEach-Object{
            $_.Name = $_.Name.Split(".")[-1]
            $props.($_.Name) = $_.Value
        }

        # Set the current path in the object to contain the data we have been passing. 
        $sourceObject.$currentPath = [pscustomobject]$props
    }
}


$schema = $hash.GetEnumerator() | 
    Select-Object Name,Value,@{Name="Parent";Expression={$split = $_.Name -split "\.";$split[0..($split.Count - 2)] -join "."}} | 
    Group-Object Parent | Sort-Object Name

# Empty Object to start
$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject 

# Build the object skeleton
$schema | ForEach-Object{Add-NestedObject $object $_.Name $_.Group}

# Show the monstrosity
$object
```

The basics is that we use group object to collect all of the values into there parent properties. They for each of those parent properties we create each node in the path (assuming that it does not already exist) using a recursive function. Once we create all the nodes then we can place the value collection inside that node.

The value collection is rebuilt as a custom object and assigned to the end node.

Here is what the thing looks like as JSON just so you can see what the object looks like now that it is converted.

```
{
    "root":  {
                 "test":  [
                              1,
                              2
                          ],
                 "Blubb":  [
                               5
                           ],
                 "controller":  {
                                    "name":  [
                                                 "10.3.3.171",
                                                 "10.3.3.172"
                                             ],
                                    "haha":  [
                                                 "hoho",
                                                 "hoho"
                                             ],
                                    "hugo":  [
                                                 12
                                             ],
                                    "test":  [
                                                 2,
                                                 2
                                             ],
                                    "upsala":  [
                                                   "handy"
                                               ],
                                    "renate":  [
                                                   123
                                               ]
                                },
                 "t":  {
                           "t1":  {
                                      "wert":  [
                                                   1
                                               ]
                                  },
                           "t2":  {
                                      "wert":  [
                                                   2
                                               ]
                                  }
                       }
             }
}
```

Comment: I am both proud and never want to see this again.

Comment: Congrats. My first 4 attempts was with recursion, but I couldn't find a way to stop it. Not sure which approach I like better, but at least this is easier to read. :-)

Comment: I was close to dumping this in favor of using invoke expression more. I think this was on general approach 3 revision 6

Comment: WOW... @FrodeF., Matt you guys are absolutely, unquestionably amazing. If I could mark two answers I would. After seeing what this takes I realize I am far out of my depth on this one. I know I'm just some nobody on the internet, but seriously, these are most impressive. The reason I chose this one as the answer is primarily because I personally feel less comfortable in my powershell use of iex and hashtables. Thank you both for this mountain of knowledge.

Comment: No problem. I've simplified my answer a bit now so it's not that overwhelming. `Invoke-Expression` runs commands just like a normal user would, but since we don't know the code to run yet (because `$hash` may be different each time), we create it dynamically.  To understand what the code does, simply remove `iex` from the script and all the lines will be printed to the screen so you could see the actual script that generates the object. You will notice that it just exactly what you described in your sample: creating nested hashtables with values and then casting them to `pscustomobject`. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that this can be done in a much more elegant way, but this is all I could think of (based on [@mjolinor's previous answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21048093/702944)).

The idea is to create a hashtable-tree with all the required levels, then insert the values where they should be (which is easier to do in a hashtable than in an object) and last but not least: cast the hashtables to `PSCustomObject`. Just like the sample/drawing in the question.

```
#Don't mind the sexy function-name
function ConvertDelimitedHashtableTo-NestedObject ([hashtable]$Hash) {

    #Hashtable to store data in
    $result = @{}

    #iex = Invoke-Expression
    #It can execute a command stored in a string.
    #It's necessary because we don't know the path before runtime (since paths depends on the inputdata).

    #Design skeleton (get path to every "parent node"/hashtable/object)
    $paths = $hash.Keys |
    #Only "delimited" keys will require a hashtable/subobject (without this, $hash = @{ 'hello' = 'world' } would fail)
    Where-Object { $_ -match '\.' } | ForEach-Object { 
        #Split string into nodes
        $parts = $_.split(".")
        0..($parts.count -2) | Foreach-Object {
            #Get every node-path except deepest level (value-node/property)
            "`$result.$($parts[0..$_] -join '.')"
        }
    } |
    #Remove duplicates
    Select-Object -Unique |
    #Sort by number of levels (because we can't create root.t before root exists)
    Sort-Object {@($_.ToCharArray() -eq '.').Count}


    #Create skeleton
    $paths | ForEach-Object {
        #Creating hashtable for each level (except values-nodes) to get a complete skeleton/tree
        iex "$_ = @{}"
    }

    #Insert values
    $hash.Keys | ForEach-Object {
        #Add values/properties to the correct hashtable with value from the input-hashtable
        iex "`$result.$_ = `$hash['$_']"
    }

    #Convert each hashtable-node to PSCustomObject
    $paths | ForEach-Object {
        iex "$_ = [pscustomobject]$_"
    }

    #Output main-hashtable as PSCustomObject
    [pscustomobject]$result
} 


#Original object
$myht = @{
    'root.Blubb' = @(5)
    'root.controller.haha' = 'hoho', 'hoho'
    'root.controller.hugo' = @(12)
    'root.controller.name' = '10.3.3.171', '10.3.3.172'
    'root.controller.renate' = @(123)
    'root.controller.test' = 2, 2
    'root.controller.upsala' = @('handy')
    'root.t.t1.wert' = @(1)
    'root.t.t2.wert' = @(2)
    'root.test' = 1, 2
}

$obj = ConvertDelimitedHashtableTo-NestedObject -Hash $myht
```

This generates and executes the following code (I removed `iex` from the script so it simply outputs each generated line of code):

```
#Manually created main hashtable: $result = @{}
#Create hashtable-skeleton
$result.root = @{}
$result.root.controller = @{}
$result.root.t = @{}
$result.root.t.t2 = @{}
$result.root.t.t1 = @{}
#Insert values
$result.root.controller.test = $hash['root.controller.test']
$result.root.controller.upsala = $hash['root.controller.upsala']
$result.root.controller.renate = $hash['root.controller.renate']
$result.root.t.t2.wert = $hash['root.t.t2.wert']
$result.root.test = $hash['root.test']
$result.root.controller.name = $hash['root.controller.name']
$result.root.controller.haha = $hash['root.controller.haha']
$result.root.Blubb = $hash['root.Blubb']
$result.root.t.t1.wert = $hash['root.t.t1.wert']
$result.root.controller.hugo = $hash['root.controller.hugo']
#Cast hashtables to objects
$result.root = [pscustomobject]$result.root
$result.root.controller = [pscustomobject]$result.root.controller
$result.root.t = [pscustomobject]$result.root.t
$result.root.t.t2 = [pscustomobject]$result.root.t.t2
$result.root.t.t1 = [pscustomobject]$result.root.t.t1
#Manually casted main hashtable to object: $obj = [pscustomobject]$result
```

And gives you this object (using `Format-Custom` to show the whole tree):

```
$obj | Format-Custom

class PSCustomObject
{
  root = 
    class PSCustomObject
    {
      t = 
        class PSCustomObject
        {
          t1 = 
            class PSCustomObject
            {
              wert = 
                [
                  1
                ]

            }
          t2 = 
            class PSCustomObject
            {
              wert = 
                [
                  2
                ]

            }
        }
      Blubb = 
        [
          5
        ]

      controller = 
        class PSCustomObject
        {
          name = 
            [
              10.3.3.171
              10.3.3.172
            ]

          haha = 
            [
              hoho
              hoho
            ]

          hugo = 
            [
              12
            ]

          test = 
            [
              2
              2
            ]

          upsala = 
            [
              handy
            ]

          renate = 
            [
              123
            ]

        }
      test = 
        [
          1
          2
        ]

    }
}
```

Comment: crap... I am almost done my answer. Hopefully it is different enough. Good work though

Comment: Thanks. Can't wait to see what you come up with. Had to start over a 1,2...5 times before I got something to work. :-)

Comment: Oh my god I am bald over this one. I just have the skeleton done of the object. Just populating it now...

Comment: It's very useful to display these types of things. Even though I didn't "win" here, I updated my answer. After some hours of sleep I figured I could simplify this alot. :)

Answer (score 1):

here is a very simple approach for nested hashtables with recursion:

```
#Example hash
$obj = @{A="B";c=@{D="F";g="H"}}


# the function
function Get-HashAsObject
{
    param ([hashtable]$hash, [switch]$Deep)

    $NewHash = @{}
    foreach ($k in $hash.Keys)
    {
        if ($hash[$k] -is [hashtable] -and $Deep)
        {
            $NewHash.Add($k,(Get-HashAsObject -Deep -hash $hash[$k]))
        }
        else
        {
            $NewHash.Add($k,$hash[$k])
        }
    }
    return [PSCustomObject]$NewHash
}

"Shallow"
$s = Get-HashAsObject $obj 
$s | fc
"Deep"
$d = Get-HashAsObject $obj -Deep
$d | fc
```

***Output:***

**Shallow**

```
class PSCustomObject
{
  A = B
  c = 
    [
      class DictionaryEntry
      {
        Key = D
        Value = F
        Name = D
      }
      class DictionaryEntry
      {
        Key = g
        Value = H
        Name = g
      }
    ]

}
```

**Deep**

```
class PSCustomObject
{
  A = B
  c = 
    class PSCustomObject
    {
      D = F
      g = H
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! after running, i was unable to do something like `$d.root` to see all properties in that level. and when i do `$d | convertto-json` the output does not match what i'm seeing with matt or frode's results

Answer (score 0):

```
# a two-liner solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947725/transform-hashtable-to-object-with-recursion

process {

    # First create the branches :
    
    $obj = $hash.keys |%{ "$_" -split "\." |% {$F=""}{(($F+=$_+".")) -replace "\.$",":"}} |
           sort-object -unique |%{ $_ -replace "[^\.]*\."," " } | ConvertFrom-Yaml

    # Then create the leaves :
    
    $hash.keys|%{ iex "`$obj.$_ = `$hash[`"$_`"]" }
}

end { 
    # just testing :
    $obj.root.controller.test
}

begin {
    $hash = @{
        'root.Blubb' = @(5)
        'root.controller.haha' = 'hoho', 'hoho'
        'root.controller.hugo' = @(12)
        'root.controller.name' = '10.3.3.171', '10.3.3.172'
        'root.controller.renate' = @(123)
        'root.controller.test' = 2, 2
        'root.controller.upsala' = @('handy')
        'root.t.t1.wert' = @(1)
        'root.t.t2.wert' = @(2)
        'root.test' = 1, 2
    }
}
```